# What was the first version of Ubuntu and where can I find it?

Tags: release-management, history-of-ubuntu

[This wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) lists Ubuntu 4.10 (Warty Warthog) as the first Ubuntu released by Canonical Ltd.

But I wanted to know whether there ever was an Ubuntu 1.x, as in Windows or Mac OS. If yes, is it available somewhere?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Ubuntu's version numbers are made using the year and month of their release date: Ubuntu 12.04 was released in April 2012, Ubuntu 11.10 on October 2011 and so on.

Ubuntu 4.10 was released in October 2004 and is the first Ubuntu release. As there wasn't any Ubuntu version released in 2001 there is no Ubuntu 1.x.

The image(s) are currently available [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/). It supported [x86](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/warty-release-install-i386.iso), [powerpc](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/warty-release-install-powerpc.iso) and [x86_64](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/warty-release-install-amd64.iso) - but of course this release is not currently supported!

Comment: That's a very short-sighted version numbering scheme. What are they planning to do in C.E. 3000+??? What will they number the version released in October 3004?

Comment: @veryhungry If Ubuntu is still around 1000 years from now, I don't think people will mix up The 2004 release with the 3004 release very easily, even if they have the same name. One will be much more temporally relevant. That said, Canonical has quite a bit of time before they have to worry about that, so they could make changes to their naming scheme later if they want to. ;)

Comment: Hmm, I'm smelling the thinking that brought about Y2K :)

Comment: @veryhungry In 1000 years, technology either won't exist or will be so unrecognizable that an "Ubuntu version" won't even make sense to anyone but historians with a specialty in archaic tools and culture.  Assuming "historians" even exist then.

Comment: If Ubuntu is still around in 985 years, they'd probably call it something like "Ubuntu X" (or maybe "Fubuntu" as a portmanteau of "future Ubuntu"?) and continue with their versioning scheme; thus "Ubuntu 4.10" would not be confused as being newer than "Ubuntu X 4.03".

Comment: @JeffGohlke We'll see…

Comment: @DoktorJ I would hope it would be Ubuntu ³4.10 :)

Answer (score 20):

Ubuntu Warty Warthog was indeed the first release by Canonical<sup>[[1]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)</sup>. You can get its image from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/4.10/).

Comment: Thank you! I've deleted my -1. For a +1 I would expect a source that definitely say that there was no version 1.0 or alternatively explains the naming scheme as Florian Diesch excplained it.